# When to summon Uber: travel from Opera to CDG

Tags: paris, uber

Tomorrow: 10AM international flight at CDG: staying at hotel near Opera.  Goal: arrive at airport no later than 7AM.

If summoning Uber:

1) How much time should I allot for transport during this time of day (75 min)?

2) Assuming 5:45AM departure, what time should I summon an Uber?

3) Is there a good way to determine the cost before deciding to use Uber over other tranport modes?

4) If I summon Uber pool, do I need to allot additional time?

The goal is to arrive at CDG airport by 7AM Monday despite any traffic or Uber process delays

Comment: I would recommend you to summon an actual taxi rather than an uber. I had a drunk uber driver in Paris just a couple of weeks ago and it really makes me question whether using uber is a good idea, especially if you have a flight to catch.

Comment: Agreed you should use an ordinary taxi if it is not tremendously more expensive.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique: Copy.  Will use a Taxi

Comment: There is also a regular bus line from Opera (the stop is rue Auber IIRC) to CDG airport if money is an issue. Before 7AM there are no traffic problems. Also, I'd recommend using a taxi if money is not an issue : the ride will cost you 50€ (flat fare) and you can book through your hotel. Saving a few €s with an Uber car is not worth the convenience IMHO.

Comment: It's okay to arrive to the airport as late as 9AM, no need to rush

Comment: Taxi was 62 euros

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This one is pretty easy to answer :)

If you leave the Opera district around 6 AM, it won't take you more than 30-40 minutes to reach CDG airport (unless there is a big incident). Trafic jam starts around 7:15-7:30 AM in this direction. So if you arrive on the highway before that, you are pretty safe!

How difficult it will be to find an Uber around 6 AM? Well, I think it should be ok. Done it several times without any issue. If you can't find one, you can take a taxi which will costs you around 60-70 €.

Then for the fare, it will be 45 €, not less, not more, if you book with Uber X.

Source :
https://www.uber.com/fr/fare-estimate/

Comment: Taxis have fixed fares for Paris/Airport rides since a few months. It'll cost exactly 50€ to go from Opera to CDG airport with a taxi.

Comment: “Not less, not more”? I thought Uber was famous for its surge pricing policy and the site in fact includes a disclaimer to that effect: “Le prix de la course peut varier selon la circulation, la météo et d'autres facteurs.”

Comment: @Relaxed You probably ignore the fact that Uber has a fixed fare for trips to and from the airport in Paris area... He will pay 45 € regardless of the time spent... Not less, not more!

Comment: @Olielo I don't know anything but you offer a link to a site explicitly stating otherwise so what's your source?

Comment: @Relaxed The page mentions 45 € for a trip from Paris Opera to CDG. This is also what I have been paying with them every time I made this trip during the last 2 years. This other source states the same : https://www.uber.com/airports/fr/cdg/ Thanks for your regular challenges on my answers! :)

Comment: It also features the sentence I just quoted. And your new source also specifically state "Les forfaits aéroports sont sujets à la tarification dynamique et peuvent donc varier en fonction de l’offre et de la demande au moment de votre commande." So basically, there is nothing special about the airport, it's *usually* €45 and there is absolutely no reason to add "nothing more, nothing less". Why not use my comments to improve your answer instead of becoming argumentative? I also frequently edit mine, that's the way this site is supposed to work!

Comment: I used Uber more than 50 times to and from the airport in the last 2 years during night time, peak trafic time, week end, etc... Always paid 45 €. Nothing less, nothing more... The sentence you are quoting is just a way for them to allow price changes when there are few Uber drivers available at the airport which never happened to me. There is no point using your comment as it just adds confusion to a clear answer...

Answer (score 7):

Since you are in an hotel, ask them to make arrangements with a taxi to pick you up so you arrive at the airport at the appropriate time.

They are used to do this.

Google maps says it should take about 35 minutes on a Monday morning.

There is usually a fixed price from the Center of Paris to the airport; so you know in advance how much it will cost you (50 euros from the Rive Droite and 55 euros from the Rive Gauche).

Answer (score 3):

Absent any traffic, it takes just over half an hour to get from your location to the airport. With morning traffic, it could take up to an hour. 75 minutes is definitely an overestimation.

Since Uber is "on demand", it can be difficult to plan too much in advance. Still, 10 minutes ought to be enough time for you to summon a car. If you are concerned about this, you can check the app when you get up to get an idea of how far away most cars are.

It should cost you somewhere in range of 40-65€.

(As mentioned in your other question, taking the bus is also an easy and cheap option based on your location.)

Answer (score 1):

In my city you can book an Uber in advance using a 15 minute time window.

This feature is called ['Schedule a Ride'](https://www.uber.com/info/scheduled-rides/) and was introduced in the last couple of months.

You can request an Uber up to 30 days in advance now, perfect for those early airport runs.

Check to see if this feature exists in Paris. My city is not listed on the Uber site so maybe Paris is the same?